# Login to Perforce from Commandline

Tags: command-line, cmd, perforce

I would like to login to Perforce(P4) from the command line.
I tried using

```
p4 -u My_Username login
```

But how do I provide the password. I need this to check-in a file from the command line.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Before connecting to the server, set P4PORT (to tell the client where the server is) and P4USER (to tell the server who you are).  P4PORT is specified as hostname:port, with the port usually (but not always) being 1666.  If you're not sure what your Perforce server address and user name are, check with your sys admin.

```
p4 set P4PORT=your.server.hostname:1666
p4 set P4USER=your.username
```

You can also use "set" or "setenv" or "export" as appropriate to your shell, but with a 2014.2 or newer Perforce client (use "p4 -V" to check your version information) you can use "p4 set" as a persistent cross-platform alternative.  Another option is to use the "-u" and "-p" flags on every command you run (e.g. "p4 -p your.server.hostname:1666 -u your.username sync ..."), but this gets tiresome quickly.

To verify that your connection is correct, run:

```
p4 info
```

If this gives you an error message, or says that your user is unknown, check with your Perforce administrator to make sure you have the correct P4PORT and P4USER values.

To login, run:

```
p4 login
```

If the client is able to connect to the server and your user name is correct, you will be prompted for the password.  Enter it and you will be logged in.

If you are scripting Perforce commands that require login credentials, and you don't want your script to stop in the middle to prompt for a password, my recommendation would be to run "p4 login" as above at some point prior to running the script.  The login ticket will persist on your machine and the script will pick it up (provided that it's connecting with the same P4PORT and P4USER that you used to generate the ticket).  This is the most secure method because your cleartext password is not stored anywhere on your machine, and the login ticket is not usable from other machines by default (it is also probably time-limited, depending on how your admin has configured things).

The insecure method is to put the plaintext password into your script:

```
echo my.formerly.secure.password|p4 login
```

Piping the cleartext of the password into the "p4 login" command will cause it to behave as if you'd entered it at the prompt, and continue executing rather than waiting for additional input.

Comment: Yea. As you said, I think as our server is ssl, the P4SSWD and -P are not working. p4 login is working but it asks me to enter a password, but as im running it from a batch file, is there a way in which when the prompt appears, I can enter the text?

Comment: In that case, yes, completely ignore everything about P4PASSWD and -P.  :)  I've removed it from my answer to eliminate any possible confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i spent 2 hours trying to get this work. I am now looking at other alternatives.

Comment: Updated my response to include some notes on scripting (you didn't mention this in your original question so I didn't think to include it).

Comment: Wow Thanks. Works brilliantly.
Apologies for not being unable to Upvote as I am a new user

Comment: @Sam Stafford can you please tell how to Login to perforce from batch file, if we didn't want to specify the password explicitly in the batch file to keep it secured. I know you already mentioned about it in your answer but I didn't get it. So please explain again. Thanks

Comment: @Aman My explanation was pretty long so I don't know that I can rephrase it in the space of a comment, especially without knowing what part wasn't clear.  :(  Maybe make a post on forums.perforce.com and a few different people can try explaining it?

Comment: You can login from the current shell using 'p4 login' post that all commands shouldn't require any login from that shell.

Answer (score 6):

**Setup Perforce login details in Windows cmd**

After installing perforce and setup your workspace through p4v, you could set up your workspace in Windows cmd.

The command you need is:

```
p4 set
```

***Set your server***

```
p4 set P4PORT= xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
```

***Set your user name***

```
p4 set P4USER=username
```

***Set your password***

If you want to secure your password, you could download the MD5 encryptor to encrypt your password.

```
p4 set P4PASSWD=hashedpasswd
```

***Set you client (workspace)***

In order to select your workspace, you could use the following command:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=nameofworkspace
```

The name of your workspace could look like: username_hostmachinename_numbers.

***Set your ignore file***

You can set up your ignore file so that when adding your project to perforce, some files (building results) could be automatically ignored.

```
p4 set P4IGNORE= filepath
```

Comment: Nice info about the password MD5 !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
p4 -P My_Password login
```

Comment: Can you give a clue about how it doesn't work please?

Comment: Throws me the following error:Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to Welcome@123 failed.
        The specified class was not found.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says in the error message - checking P4PORT?  It looks like it can't connect to the server - nothing to do with passwords.

Comment: To specify the port, use lower-case '-p'. So a full command would be: 'p4 -p my_port -u my_user login'. To specify the password, you can pass the password on stdin, or via the -P (upper-case '-P') flag.

Comment: I have resolver the port issue. As it is ssl connection, open passwords are not being accepted. So im now looking at other commands like "p4 login" and then entering the password manually when the prompt appears

Comment: As Im running a set of commads from a batch file, is there a way in which I can enter my password, when the prompt appears

Comment: I can double-verify that -P doesn't work in a similar configuration. This solution may work for some setups but it doesn't work at all in ours.

Comment: I suspect that, like the poster of this question, the issue you're having is not the one posed in the question. My answer gives what was asked. The accepted answer fixes a problem which isn't what was asked, but which evidently turned out to be the real problem.

Comment: Doing `p4 -P pwd login` doesn't use `pwd` to login and acquire a new ticket.  The `-P pwd` overrides P4PASSWD from the environment; this can be used to authenticate (for any command), but `p4 login` will always prompt for the password regardless of what P4PASSWD is set to.